# image height doesn't wraping content inside listview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-imageview, cardslib

I have a problem while working with List view and cardslib library.
I created a card list with the same structure of list_card_thumbnail_layout
and each card contains a photo and text
I used for card layout card_thumbnail_layout
But the source of all thumbnails is an already loaded bitmap
What I want is make the thumbnail match the width of the card and scale itself to fit inside the thumbnail
What I did is:
For card List:

```
<it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.view.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/list_cardId"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/list_card.thumbnail"
    card:card_layout_resourceID="@layout/card_thumbnail_layout"
    />
```

For indivisual Card:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:card="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.view.component.CardThumbnailView
                style="@style/card_thumbnail_outer_layout"
                android:id="@+id/card_thumbnail_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <!-- Main Content View -->
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/card_main_content_layout"
                style="@style/card.content_outer_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and in styles:

```
<style name="card_thumbnail_image">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:scaleType">centerCrop</item>
    </style>

    <style name="card_thumbnail_outer_layout">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    </style>
```

I don't know where the problem is. :(

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think the attribute 'adjustViewBounds' is the answer in this case

give this a try:

```
<style name="card_thumbnail_image">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:scaleType">centerInside</item>
    <item name="android:adjustViewBounds">true</item>
</style>
```